# ENOENT ERROR using fs.unlink in a Express.js Simple APP?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, filesystems

js.And i'm creating a simple blog in express.js.
I use   [Typicode/lowdb as database](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb) , to create/update/delete, posts based on the id on a data.json file.And use the slug data in the json array to create/update/delete markdown posts with the **Node.js File System API**.On the **delete side**  of the markdown posts i get an error that i don't understand.

```
  { [Error: ENOENT, unlink 'C:\Users\path\to\publicfolder\undefined.md']
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\path\\to\\publicfolder\\undefined.md' }
```

I'm using **fs.unlink** like this to remove markdown posts:

```
   var oldSlug = "public/"+req.params.slug+".md";   

fs.unlink(oldSlug, function(err) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("Deleted the old markdown file: " + oldSlug +"");
    }
  });
```

Here is some example of the code exposed by parts:

**Example to create/update/delete Posts - Post.js**

```
       exports.index = function (req, res) {
        res.render('post/index', { posts: db.list()});
    }; 

    exports.form = function (req, res) {
            res.render('post/form');
        };

        exports.edit = function (req, res) {
        var post = db.getById(req.params.id);
        res.render('post/edit', {post: post})
        }

       exports.update = function (req, res) {

        var slugTitle = slug(req.body.name).toLowerCase().split('.').join("");

        var description = req.body.desc;

    db.update({id: req.body.id, name: req.body.name, desc: req.body.desc,
    slug: slugTitle});

//using this to rename and update markdown posts it work's

        var oldPath = "public/"+req.body.slug+".md";
         var newPath = "public/"+slugTitle+".md"; 

         fs.unlink(oldPath, function(err) {
            if(err) {
              console.log(err);
            } else {
              console.log("Deleted the old markdown file : oldPath ");
            }
          }); 
        fs.writeFile(newPath, description, function(err) {
                    if(err) {
                      console.log(err);
                    } else {
                      console.log("The post was updated as: newPath ");
                    }
                  }); 
        res.redirect('/post');};

        exports.remove = function (req, res) {
            db.remove(req.params.id);

//using this to delete markdown posts i get the error
//changing req.params.slug to req.body.slug still gives the error 

          var oldSlug = "public/"+req.params.slug+".md"; 
            fs.unlink(oldSlug, function(err) {
            if(err) {
              console.log(err);
            } else {
              console.log("Deleted the markdown file: " + oldSlug +"");
            }
          });
        res.redirect('/post');};
```

**Example on Server.js**

```
app.get('/post', post.index);
app.get('/post/create', post.form);
app.post('/post/create', post.save);
app.get('/post/details/:id', post.details);
app.get('/post/edit/:id', post.edit);
app.post('/post/update', post.update);
app.get('/post/delete/:id', post.remove);
 http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
 });
```

**Example of a index.jade**

```
doctype
html
    head
        title
    body
        h1 Posts
        ul
        each item in posts
            li Item #{item.name} - #{item.desc} - #{item.slug} 
                a(href='/post/details/#{item.id}') Details -
                a(href='/post/edit/#{item.id}') Edit -
                a(href='/post/delete/#{item.id}') Delete
        div
            p
                a(href='post/create') Add new
```

**The problem is on the exports.remove function in post.js file but why??I believe i'm identifying the markdown file to delete that corresponds to the Slug params from the document in the database or not?** I Hope i'm making sense in the code.

Comment: Do you check the file "C:\\Users\\path\\to\\publicfolder\\undefined.md" exist or not? Maybe the `req.body.slug` is `undefined`. You never pass `slug` from the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not passing the variable `slug` anywhere to your `remove` route. Since you are using GET it can't come from req.body, so you have to either pass it in the URL path or as query string.

Try changing these lines:

`post.js`

```
var oldSlug = "public/"+req.query.slug+".md";
```

`index.jade`

```
a(href='/post/delete/#{item.id}?slug=#{item.slug}') Delete
```

Comment: Thanks **VICTORKOHL** i never tought about that.I am really inexperienced with Node.js and Express.js.I hope you dont think this is ridiculous but can we use POST METHOD TO A REMOVE ROUTE??Something in a form like this: <code>form(id='form', action='/post/delete', method='POST') </code>**Once Again thanks a lot for your answer**

Comment: Sorry about the question above POST method to a remove  route?!!.I'm still learning Express.js routing, a efficient method is to use DELETE not POST.

Comment: No problem. Yes, it is better to use DELETE to remove things.

Comment: I have a related problem.  Are you willing to comment?  Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38625483/error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-with-angular2-and-express-js