# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory with Angular2 and Express.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, angular

I am making minor modifications to [this sample Angular2 app on GitHub](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter) so that it uses Express.js instead of KOA.  But at the moment, the following error is printed in the `nodemon` console when I try to load the app in FireFox:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory
```

The Angular2 app starts to load when an http request for `localhost : 8080` triggers the `*` router handler, which returns `index.html`, which then triggers callbacks for a series of nested dependencies, one of which throws the error and halts the application loading mid-way through.

**What specific changes need to be made to the code in the GitHub sample in order to resolve the `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory`?**

---

**Background and Code:**

---

Here is the new replacement for [`router.js`](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter/blob/master/server/router.js) which uses Express.js instead of KOA:

```
'use strict';
let uuid = require('node-uuid');
var path = require('path');
let jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
let config = require('./config');

// expose the routes to our app with module.exports
module.exports = function(app) {

    //all other methods omitted here for brevity

    app.get('*', function(req, res) {
        console.log('inside * route!');           
        if(req.url === '/'){
            res.sendFile(path.resolve('dist/client/index.html')); // load the single view file (angular will handle the front-end)
        } else {
            res.sendFile(path.resolve('./dist/client' + req.url));
        }
    });
};
```

The `nodemon` console output for the request to `localhost : 8080` that triggers the above Express.js `app.get('*'...)` method repeatedly leading up to the error is:

```
App listening on port 8080
inside * route!
GET / 304 54.261 ms - -
inside * route!
inside * route!
inside * route!
GET /boot.css 304 4.637 ms - -
GET /boot.js 304 4.447 ms - -
GET /vendor.js 304 3.742 ms - -
inside * route!
GET /vendor.js.map 200 3.180 ms - 3115631
inside * route!
GET /boot.js.map 200 2.366 ms - 61810
inside * route!
GET /bootstrap.css.map 404 2.515 ms - 169
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/user/nodejs_apps/angular2_oauth_seed_app/dist/client/bootstrap.css.map'
    at Error (native)
```

And the new [`server/index.js`](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-esnext-starter/blob/master/server/index.js) which specifies Express.js is:

```
// set up ======================================================================
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();                               // create our app w/ express
var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;                // set the port
var morgan = require('morgan');             // log requests to the console (express4)
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');    // pull information from HTML POST (express4)
var methodOverride = require('method-override'); // simulate DELETE and PUT (express4)

app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/dist/client'));
app.use(morgan('dev'));                                         // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended':'true'}));            // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json());                                     // parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/'));

// load the routes
require('./router')(app);

// listen (start app with node server.js) ======================================
app.listen(port);
console.log("App listening on port " + port);
```

**Everything else in the GitHub sample app remains the same as what you see on GitHub** with the exception of `package.json`, which merely contains dependencies to support the alterations in `router.js` and `index.js` as shown above.

Comment: `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory`, there is no such file. You should always check file stats before sending it. And It's unlikely that you need to send file manually.

Comment: maybe you should try `path.resolve(__dirnamne, 'dist/client/index.html')`. (add `__dirname` to resolve)

Comment: @MoLow Your suggestion leads in an error stating that `__dirname` is not defined in `router.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bootstrap.css.map` indicates that your browser is trying to load a source map (which is a debugging tool) for the Bootstrap CSS.

This will only happen if you have your browser's developer tools open, so not strictly a problem (unless you want to actually debug Bootstrap's CSS). Besides that, it's always possible to other URL's to be requested and yield the same error.

A solution would be to add an explicit error handler to `sendFile`, and assume that when an error happens, it's because the file doesn't exist (so it should yield a 404 response):

```
res.sendFile(path.resolve('./dist/client' + req.url), (err) => {
  if (err) return res.sendStatus(404);
});
```

Comment: @FirstOfMany you probably want a Gulp task that copies the Bootstrap source map to a location where Express can find it (`./dist/client`).

Comment: Thank you and +1 for adding value here.  The solution did NOT require a new Gulp task because nothing in the client changed from the previous version.